# preg_replace UNLESS string exists

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to add CSS styling to all hyperlinks *unless* it has a "donttouch" attribute.

E.g.

- Style this: `<a href="http://whatever.com">style me</a>`
- Don't style this: `<a href="http://whatever.com" donttouch>don't style me</a>`

Here's my preg_replace without the "donttouch" exclusion, which works fine.

```
preg_replace('/<a(.*?)href="([^"]*)"(.*?)>(.*?)<\/a>/','<a$1href="$2"$3><span style="color:%link_color%; text-decoration:underline;">$4</span></a>', $this->html)
```

I've looked all over the place, and would appreciate any help.

Comment: You may be better off using a real HTML parser for this.

Comment: @Arjan It's generating a template for use in an email, so CSS classes are unfortunately out of the question---all CSS has to be inline

Comment: [obligatory link to that one question that will explain everything](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Answer (score 0):

Find (works also in Notepad++)

```
(?s)(<a (?:(?!donttouch)[^>])+>)(.*?)</a>
```

Replace with (Replace all in Notepad++):

```
\1<span style="whatever">\2</span></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished without a regular expression. Instead, use a CSS attribute selector.

For example, use these rules:

```
a { font-weight: bold; color: green }
a[donttouch=''] { font-weight: normal; color: blue }
```

Technically, you are styling the elements with the 'donttouch' attribute, but you can use default values. This will be more efficient than attempting to use a regular expression to parse your HTML, which is usually a bad idea.

Comment: Thanks, George. It's generating a template for use in an email, so unfortunately all CSS needs to be inline